# Will capacitors that are connected between GND and Vcc to a CPU impact the capacitance between the same pins on other components?

Tags: pcb-design, component-selection

I am working  on a pcb that has to have a CPU with capacitors between its gnd and vcc pins,  other components like sensors also have to have capacitors connected to them for whatever reason indicated in the datasheet, and these capacitors are also connected between gnd and vcc, but capacitors between the 2 pins will impact the overall capacitances on the entire board.

For example, if I need a 10pF capacitor between vcc-gnd pins of a CPU, and another one between vcc-gnd pins of a sensor, the equivalent capacitance will become 20pF, and if these kind of connections are too frequent, I will end up with a huge equivalent capacitance that may not work well for those components.

Comment: Why do you think adding up a few or a few hundred of 10pF capacitors would not work well?

Comment: This is only an example, suppose you have hundreds of 1uF capacitors, then your sensor that required 100pF as decoupling cap will endup with hundreds uF of equivalent capacitance, which does not respect datasheet specs.

Comment: Capacitance on a power network stabilizes voltage and reduces noise. Noise is bad, so usually you would not think of your system having low noise and highly stable power as a problem.

Comment: @mathssoso Bear in mind that anything less than about 10 nF is extremely unlikely to ever be used as a decoupling capacitor. Capacitors in the pF range are usually used for other purposes.

Comment: "I am working on a pcb that has to have a CPU with capacitors between its gnd and vcc pins". Isn't that true of _all_ CPUs, and indeed most chips in general?

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff yes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, but.

Decoupling capacitors work best when they're as close as possible to the pins of the IC (some ICs even have internal decoupling capacitors placed directly on top of the silicon die itself). A capacitor providing decoupling to one chip will not necessarily be adequate decoupling for another chip a few inches away, even if it's nominally enough capacitance for them both.

At low frequencies (e.g. when measured with a multimeter), two capacitors associated with different chips will indeed measure as the sum of their capacitances. But at higher frequencies the impedance of the connecting traces (which is most of the reason these capacitors are used!) will become significant.

Outside of the outputs of amplifiers, it's unusual for too *much* capacitance to cause a problem, especially if it has significant series impedance (due to being halfway across the board). Note that linear regulators are amplifiers and can exhibit this type of instability, though modern ones are typically more tolerant of large output capacitances. Switching converters, as long as they use some form of soft-start, are unlikely to go unstable, though the cheapest ones might have issues starting up into a 10 mF load.

Decoupling capacitors halfway across the board are not generally something you will need to worry about for any chips other than your PMICs, and then only in fairly extreme cases.

---

Also, you're extremely unlikely to be using 10 pF capacitors for decoupling. It's usually 100 nF for most chips, a few to a few dozen μF for regulators, and probably somewhere in the 1 to 100 nF range for complex CPUs and FPGAs (times a lot, for the dozens of power supply pins that need decoupling).

Comment: There can be such as too much capavitance on a power supply. They might become unstable, or there may be a limit for maximum capacitance due to some specification which devices must pass, like USB.

Comment: @Justme Yes, but I would consider USB a somewhat unusual case. As for power supplies becoming unstable, that's also less common with modern regulators, but you're right that it is something to consider.

Comment: More generally to say -- regulators are amplifiers, so are subject to the same stability considerations; whether they're stable with any load, or not, can be proven by design or testing. There can be energy limits, whether due to startup current or power, switching capacity (like for USB), or etc. Often, one or another consideration dominates in a given application, but it may be worth mentioning all for completeness.

Comment: Why is USB unusual? People use it daily for memory sticks to charging laptops at 100W, so specifications and standard compliance is important. Also, put too many millifarads to a simple buck regulator and it likely fails to start, no matter how modern it is, unless soft start is utilized. But hardly adding hundreds of 10pF caps is near the limit though.

Comment: @Justme It's unusual to me, perhaps; I rarely use anything USB in my circuit designs, even just for power.

Comment: +1 to say that generally, you have a capacitor somewhere on your power rail (if it's a PMIC/regulator) that is on the order of at least uF (required by the regulator), and even if you use 10nF decoupling caps, you would need dozens to move the total capacitance in a meaningful way, and scores or hundreds before it pushed a typical capacitor outside of its tolerances.

Comment: Also, 10pF is useful up to 2 GHz. We don't know what CPU is being used. Even simple MCUs go to 500 MHz, and a generic 100nF cap is useful only up to 50 MHz.

Comment: @Hearth To that point -- it may be illuminating to readers to provide such context. In a few posts, I've taken to adding some background of my perspective, where I'm coming from, what my biases may be. This likely isn't relevant to the more casual readers so is ignored as if not provided anyway, so no harm there, but it speaks to the more critical or experienced audience that can draw nuance from it, or offer deeper insight into what you blind spots are (as we're, in part, feeling out in this very comment thread). :)